# EFCore.BulkExtensions - BulkUpdate using pimarykey

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, efcore.bulkextensions

We are trying to BulkUpdate([EFCore.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions)) a table based on primary key. We need to update ONLY `Name` based on `Id` and not `Age`

Model

```
public class Student 
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Primary Key
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code I used to try to update a student's name using primary key Id

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
students.Add(new Student()
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Name 1",
    Age = 25
});

var updateByProperties = new List<string> { nameof(Student.Id) };
var propToExclude = new List<string> { nameof(Student.Id) };
var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig { UpdateByProperties = updateByProperties, PropertiesToExclude = propToExclude };
_dbContext().BulkUpdate(students, bulkConfig);
```

My expectation here is it will update column `Name` of a row which has `Id` as 1 but I am getting the following error

```
The given key 'Id' was not present in the dictionary.
```

So how do I BulkUpdate(EFCore.BulkExtensions) a table based on primary key.

Answer (score 5):

Let's suppose that `Id` is a **primary key (PK)** and you need to update ONLY `Name` based on `Id` and not `Age`.

It is needed to set `PropertiesToInclude` attribute within `BulkConfig`. Attention: you do not have to use `PropertiesToInclude` and `PropertiesToExclude` at the same time. (If you want to include more than half attributes, it is better to use `PropertiesToExclude`, but in your case you want to change only Name, so we will use the attribute Include).

Also, it is not needed to define `UpdateByProperties`, because you want to update data by `Id` (which is PK). `UpdateByProperties` define attributes which are used as lookup for updating.

So the code should be like that:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
students.Add(new Student()
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Name 1",
    Age = 25
});

var propToInclude = new List<string> { nameof(Student.Name) };
var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig { PropertiesToInclude = propToInclude };
_dbContext().BulkUpdate(students, bulkConfig);
```